# Cocos2d make physics body passable by anything

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm trying to make a static physics body that can be passed by anything like it isn't there (like an ordinary sprite). Infinite restitution doesn't work apparently. Is this possible?

I'm trying to simulate climbing a ladder so I need to handle the contact while also making the ladder passable by the player body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Chipmunk (default physics in Cocos2d-x):

in the object A's physics initializer

```
// Chipmunk collision
int a = 1;// 0000 0001
physicsBody->setCategoryBitmask(a);
```

in the object B's physics initializer

```
int b = 0;// 0000 0000
physicsBody->setCollisionBitmask(b);// a & b will == 0 => no collision.
// 

int c = 1;// 0000 0001
physicsBody->setContactTestBitmask(c);
// a & c will != 0 => will call onContact...() help you handle manually
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I succeeded. All I had to do was return false on collision callback.